# Use of "Can" x "Could"

Tags: word-choice

In the phrases below:

After all the harm you've done to me how **can** I say I still love you?

After all the harm you've done to me how **could** I say I still love you?

...are the use of both "can" and "could" correct?

In Portuguese, although with some slight differences in meaning, both can be used, but I'm not sure the same applies in English.

Comment: If you edit your question to include a fuller context, and the intention of the speaker, you'll get clearer answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both grammatically correct.

Without context or tone of voice, it's impossible to say what they mean. They both share (at least) two possible meanings:

> A "How is it possible for me to say I still love you?"
> and
> B "It's impossible for me to say I still love you."

The first is *more likely* to be used by someone intending meaning A, and the second is *more likely* to be used by someone meaning B.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply, it really helped me. Sorry if I didn't provide more details in my question, but the more I tried to be more specific the more the question seemed to become confusing. The examples you provided were great.